# Drop a layer in php array and drop fields also

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 3 dimensional array and I am trying to drop the base key of my array so that only the 2 higher key/value pairs are displayed.

At the same time there are 2 fields that I am trying to delete but the code: unset($TestArray['Total']); 
unset($TestArray['Count_all']);
has not worked.

Qu 1) How can I drop the fields "Total" and "Count_all" from the array?

Qu 2) How can I reduce the array in fig 1 to the array in fig 2? (Preferably making the array numeric at the new base level rather than associative). Fig 2 is exactly what I am trying to get the original array to look like.

Sorry if my wording does not describe very well what I am trying to do.

FIG 1

```
Array
(
    [86] => Array
        (
            [134] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 86
                    [Total_Amount] => 36.00
                )

            [130] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 86
                    [Total_Amount] => 28.00
                )

            [135] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 86
                    [Total_Amount] => 125.00
                )

            [131] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 86
                    [Total_Amount] => 67.00
                )

            [133] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 86
                    [Total_Amount] => 368.80
                )

            [Total] => 624.8
            [Count_all] => 5
        )

    [67] => Array
        (
            [130] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 67
                    [Total_Amount] => 129.58
                )

            [131] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 67
                    [Total_Amount] => 230.25
                )

            [133] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 67
                    [Total_Amount] => 76.20
                )

            [132] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 67
                    [Total_Amount] => 436.03
                )

            [Total] => 872.06
            [Count_all] => 4
        )

    [87] => Array
        (
            [132] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 87
                    [Total_Amount] => 106.5
```

FIG 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User_ID] => 8
            [Item_ID] => 86
            [Total_Amount] => 36.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [User_ID] => 8
            [[Item_ID] => 86
            [Total_Amount] => 28.00
        )
    [2] => Array
```

etc.

Comment: Please can someone edit this. The top part of the arrays in fig 1 and fig 2 are not displaying.

Comment: what do you mean by Blockquote ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply loop throught your array :)

```
<?php 
$array_input;
$array_output  = array();
$blackListKeys = array("Total", "Count_all");

foreach ($array_input as $array_input1) {
    foreach ($array_input1 as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, $blackListKeys)) continue;
        else                                $array_output[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Halayem. 2 things would make this perfect:
1)  The 2 unrequired fields are messing things up as they appear in the array as item 5 and 6.

[5] => 624.8
[6] => 5

Comment: Ran out of editing time. Do you know how I can remove the two unrequired fields as they are messing up the array - see items 5 and 6 below?

[5] => 624.8
[6] => 5

Answer (score 1):

Your `unset($TestArray['Total'])` code won't work because the 'Total' key (and Count_all key for the other part) are within an array.  Using the example you have:

```
Array
(
    [86] => Array
        (
            [134] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 86
                    [Total_Amount] => 36.00
                )

            [130] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 86
                    [Total_Amount] => 28.00
                )

            [135] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 86
                    [Total_Amount] => 125.00
                )

            [131] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 86
                    [Total_Amount] => 67.00
                )

            [133] => Array
                (
                    [User_ID] => 8
                    [Item_ID] => 86
                    [Total_Amount] => 368.80
                )

            [Total] => 624.8
            [Count_all] => 5
        )
);
```

The array key you'd need (assuming that array is the `$TestArray` would be `unset($TestArray[86]['Total'];`.

For the second part of the question, you'd need to iterate through the first array and build a new array from the values.  Again, assuming your first array example is `$TestArray` you could do something along the lines of:

```
$newArray = array(); // this will be the array in the correct format
foreach ($TestArray as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
}
```

This also has the advantage of removing the Total and Count_all indexes as they aren't arrays

Comment: Thanks for solution Gabe, however  "Total" and "Count_all" still appeared after running that code. 

Your code: unset($TestArray[86]['Total']); worked so thanks for showing me how to do that.

Comment: If you use the `$newArray` variable, the Total and Count_all shouldn't be there are they aren't arrays.

Comment: Your code produced the array as I wanted it apart from not excluding "Total" and "Count_all". 
Aren't "Total" and "Count_all" associative array items at the "86" level?

Answer (score 1):

Everything worth doing is worth over-doing it ;-)
In PHP7 (because of the [anonymous class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php)) you can do something like:

```
<?php
$src = array(
    86 => array(
        134 => array('User_ID'=>8, 'Item_ID'=>86, 'Total_Amount'=>'36.00'),
        130 => array('User_ID'=>8, 'Item_ID'=>86, 'Total_Amount'=>'28.00'),
        135 => array('User_ID'=>8, 'Item_ID'=>86, 'Total_Amount'=>'125.00'),
        131 => array('User_ID'=>8, 'Item_ID'=>86, 'Total_Amount'=>'67.00'),
        133 => array('User_ID'=>8, 'Item_ID'=>86, 'Total_Amount'=>'368.00'),
        'Total' => '624.8',
        'Count_all' => 5
    ),

    67 => array(
        134 => array('User_ID'=>8, 'Item_ID'=>67, 'Total_Amount'=>'129.58'),
        130 => array('User_ID'=>8, 'Item_ID'=>67, 'Total_Amount'=>'230.25'),
        135 => array('User_ID'=>8, 'Item_ID'=>67, 'Total_Amount'=>'76.20'),
        131 => array('User_ID'=>8, 'Item_ID'=>67, 'Total_Amount'=>'436.03'),
        'Total' => '872.06',
        'Count_all' => 4
    )
);

$iter = array_reduce(
    $src,
    function($it, $e) {
        $it->append( 
            new class(new ArrayIterator($e)) extends FilterIterator {
                public function accept() {
                    return !in_array($this->key(), array('Total', 'Count_all'));
                }
            }
        );
        return $it; 
    },
    new AppendIterator
);

foreach($iter as $v) {
    echo join(', ', $v), "\r\n";
}
```

prints

```
8, 86, 36.00
8, 86, 28.00
8, 86, 125.00
8, 86, 67.00
8, 86, 368.00
8, 67, 129.58
8, 67, 230.25
8, 67, 76.20
8, 67, 436.03
```

see also:
http://docs.php.net/spl
http://docs.php.net/array_reduce

Comment: btw: I do not suggest that you actually use this code for your actual problem. But.... it doesn't hurt if you understand the concept(s) ;-) For other sources and depending on what processing is done (or not done), it might be fruitful.